# Five teens have rings that give them elemental powers

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

It was nearly 2003 or 2004 when I used to see that cartoon show almost everyday on Fox Kids. However, I was of 6 or 7 years at that time and in spite of watching that show regularly I had completely forgotten its name and much of the characters.

What I still remember is that there were five persons (some young guys and girls) that were all having a ring with some special powers (something like *water, wind, earth* etc). Other than these five persons there was also another superhero (probably the central protagonist of the show and the torch bearer of these five young people). He was having some extra special powers like flying, strength, etc. As far as I remember he was addressed as **Captain**.

And in a whole this show was based on saving the environment from the evil nature perishers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The show you describe sounds exactly like [Captain Planet and the Planeteers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Planet_and_the_Planeteers)
[image]

- 5 young adults who were given rings that when combined with a mantra, summoned Captain Planet
- Show was very much about environmentalism
- Villains were called Eco-Villains

Comment: I'd say this too, but op also said 2003 or 2004 on fox kids. Captain Planet was never on fox, and not in syndication those years. It originally aired early 90s.

Comment: @cde I suspect that the OP is misremembering the details about when/how they watched the show, because there's no way they're describing anything other than Captain Planet.

Comment: [It could be this live-action version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwJaELXadKo&t=5s)?

Comment: Their powers were Earth, Fire, Wind, Water and Heart.

Comment: Cartoon Network/Boomerang has aired a 12 hour marathon of this show on Earth Day many times since the 90s. Perhaps the OP caught one of those marathons.

Comment: I always felt a little sorry for the kid who got the "Heart" power. Didn't really stack up to the other ones.